# Label can't access added attribute

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, fields-attributes, feature-layer

I have a layer that gets created with a couple of attributes, one of which is `NAME`. Then I create a `LabelLayer` and add a feature layer like so:

```js
layerLabel.addFeatureLayer(layerDisplay, rendererLbl, "{NAME}", { pointPriorities: 'CenterCenter' });
```

And this works fine. The `NAME` is displayed where I'd expect it to be displayed. But, I also want to add more attributes, so I have some code that adds an attribute called `VALUE` and then, on the `update-end` event of `layerDisplay`, I add my label layer like so:

```js
layerLabel.addFeatureLayer(layerDisplay,  rendererLbl, "{NAME} {VALUE}", { pointPriorities: 'CenterCenter' });
```

But it will display as, for example: `Alaska {VALUE}`. Why won't it see the `VALUE` attribute? If I add a break point before the label layer is added, I can do this:

```js
console.log(layerDisplay.graphics[0].attributes);
```

And I can see that both the `NAME` and the `VALUE` attributes are there.

A little hacking around, and I *could* (but would rather not) do this before adding my feature layer:

```js
layerLabel._buildLabelText = function (b, d, c, e) {
    return d.NAME + " " + d.VALUE;
}
```

Overwriting the existing internal `_buildLabelText` function. Obviously, I'd prefer not to have to do this, but it is instructive that the object passed as `d` has all the properties (including `NAME` and `VALUE`) that I want, so I'm still confused as to why the regular function was unable to match them up.

Comment: will it display value if you only use it? If so try something like {name} & {value}

Comment: The value is used on the `layerDisplay` layer to actually color the map, so the data is there and is being used, but the `layerLabel` layer refuses to see it. The renderer for the `layerDisplay` is a `ClassBreaksRenderer` that calls a function that adds in the `VALUE` attribute to the original objects passed to it. This function gets called on everything in the `layerDisplay` before the `layerLabel` even gets added. I tried using the same `ClassBreaksRenderer` (rather than a `SimpleRenderer`) for the `addFeatureLayer`, but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: but will it display label as rendered by itself?

Comment: @BradNesom: Not sure what you are asking. I'm really a bit lost in this arcgis stuff.

Comment: I'm just asking remove the name label and try to only label the value. That will help troubleshoot the problem

Comment: @BradNesom: Oh, now I understand. Yeah, I've tried that and several variations on it (even adding a whole separate layer for just the `VALUE` part). Nothing so far has convinced it to display the actual value rather than the text `{VALUE}`

Comment: is value a domain field?

Comment: @BradNesom: If you mean was it originally an `outField` when we created a new `FeatureLayer`, no. It comes from a different source.

Comment: I wish my chat wasn't blocked we would use chat. No what I mean is... Is this an esri gdb or a spatially enabled data source? if esri gdb is the field a domain field? Which means there are values in it that relate to a table of values. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/tables/design-defining-fields-in-tables.htm

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after some hacking around it looks like the parameter `c` to the `_buildLabelText` above is actually the `fields` array of `layerDisplay`. It looks like the function looks for a match in there (by name) before it'll do any substitutions. If I add this:

```
layerDisplay.fields.push({
    alias: "VALUE",
    length: 10,
    name: "VALUE",
    type: "esriFieldTypeString"
});
```

Then the it will substitute `{VALUE}` with the `VALUE` property of the attributes (without needing to replace `_buildLabelText`)